# What is the name of a set of parallel edges in a multigraph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, multigraphs

In directed multigraph, two vertices, $a$ and $b$, may have zero or more parallel edges connecting them in one direction or the other.  Does this set of parallel edges have a name?  I seem to remember reading a book which gave this set a name.

Comment: I found almost what I'm looking for.  The book "Introduction to Graph Theory" by Richard J. Trudeau, calls a "skein" two vertices together with 2 or more edges connecting them.